# When does resonance occurs given an ODE, and why?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag, oscillators, resonance

For example given the equation $y''+by=sin^{2}(2t)$. I am asked to calculate value of $b$ needed for resonance.

Is this like saying when the frequency of the general solution is the same as the frequency of the particular?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The term $b$ is in the position of $\omega_0^2$. And you need to convert
$$
   \sin^2(2 t) = \sin^2\left(\frac{4t}{2}\right) = \frac{1-\cos 4t}{2}
$$

to observe the driving frequency.